# Add multi colored custom icon in hugo

Tags: html, css, sass, hugo

A newbie to css 
I’m trying to add my custom icon to my hugo website. I am using v0.67.1. I am able to add a single colored logo but how can I to add multi color custom icon to the skill page. My css look like this https://gist.github.com/mridulbirla/bb0b28b91bdd84d4d67db78bd66fcae4. 
I was able to reference

```
.icon-apachespark:before {
  content: "\e901";
  color: #e25a1c;
}
```

in my skills.md page like this

```
[[feature]]
  icon = \"apachespark"
  icon_pack = "icon"
  name = "Apache Spark"
  description = "40%"
```

I want to add icon of icon-hadoop-logo-svg-vector which kind of nested

Comment: Try using SVG icons instead. Font icons will not support multicolors